# Normalize.css how to use it?

Tags: html, css

This may be a silly question but it's not obvious for me. I read it helps keep browser consistency etc..

However it says nothing about how to use it. Do I just... include it? Is that it? Where do I include it? Before my stylesheets or after?

I presume it does something with the code I myself write so I'm guessing I add it after my css code.

https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/3.0.3/normalize.min.css

Is that the correct file. It seems very small.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Do I just... include it? Is that it?

Yes

> Where do I include it? Before my stylesheets or after?

Before. You normalize and then you deviate from "normal". It doesn't make sense to reset to normal after you have applied your custom styles.

> Is that the correct file.

Yes.

> It seems very small.

It doesn't do much.